# When we jump in the opposite direction the earth is moving, why do we fall back?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I've watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU) a while back that talks about how gravity is actually not a force, but objects are in constant motion. For example when we're falling from the sky, it's the earth that's actually speeding towards us, not pulling us towards it.

My guess is that the air is also moving with us at the same speed of the earth, so when we jump, the air pushes us back to the surface. Now this might answer why we fall back, but how do we explain the air being anchored to earth ?

Comment: *"For example when we're falling from the sky, it's the earth that's actually speeding towards us, not pulling us towards it."* - the accepted convention for the resolution of this ambiguity is to treat the larger mass as stationary. Otherwise you'd have people saying that they didn't drive their car into the tree - rather, the tree ploughed into them. Also, there is no practical distinction between the "field" and the "curved space" explanations - the former tends to be a more common sense and generalisable conception, whereas the latter is preferred by many who are steeped in mathematics.

Comment: This still doesn't provide a solution for the question of how I return to the surface after I jump in the opposite direction of the earth's motion. I should have less speed after I jump which means i should be left behind normally.

Comment: the answer is very simple. The gravity of the Earth pulls you back toward the ground. It's completely immaterial that the Earth itself is moving through the solar system - the Earth will pull *you* back towards *itself*, regardless of whether you jump off from the 'fast' side (i.e. so that you jump ahead of the Earth along its orbit), or jump from the 'slow' side (i.e. jumping against the orbit of the Earth).

Comment: Ah yes, I completely forgot that I'll still be following the geodesic even if I launch off the surface of the earth. In matter of fact, if I'm standing in the opposite direction the earth is moving, the earth would be actually speeding away from me, but still I'm kept on the ground thanks to the curvature in spacetime. So there is a force making me follow the geodesics. Is that force actually gravity ? Do we know why a force is created because of the curvature in spacetime ?

Comment: I believe (and I stand to be corrected on this...) their argument would be that you are always moving ahead in time, axiomatically. But by curving spacetime, that movement onwards along a straight line no longer entails you remaining stationary in space, instead your position approaches that of the Earth. This is not on account of any force - you are hurtling straight ahead through spacetime on inertia alone - but you are moving through a spacetime that is itself curved towards the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

You and the earth attract each other, but your acceleration is bigger.

Comment: When you say attract, that implies that gravity is a force, but according to general relativity it's not. This is what makes me confused. When I jump in the opposite direction, there is nothing pulling me to the earth. We were just moving in the same direction, but now I have less speed so logically i should fall behind. But that doesn't happen.

Comment: @ElyesMansour, gravity *is* a force. As I said in my comment to your question, some prefer to talk of "curved spacetime", but it amounts to exactly the same. I don't find it a very satisfactory conception myself, but you'd have to understand how the geometry is worked to understand exactly why some physicists prefer to think of curved spacetime than of a force field.

Comment: Keep in mind that in the vicinity of the earth, it is the mass of the earth which is the primary cause of curved space-time.  You can't jump away from that.